# Imperavi redactor.js table plugin with bullets

Tags: html-lists, redactor

I would like to add an unordered list in the table of the Redactor WYSIWYG-editor but I cannot get it work. Other formatted text like bold, links etc. work. It just does not seem to work in the table plugin. Did anyone manage to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the same issue and my plugin version is 2.11. In this plugin I have to modify some code to make it work.

Go to line number 6913 where you will find the code

```
list: function() {
```

in toggle function comment out the following block of code:

```
if (this.utils.inBlocks(['table', 'td', 'th', 'tr']))
{
    return;
}
```

Then later you need to comment 1 more line at line number 6996:

```
$listParent.replaceWith($listParent.contents());
```

After commenting out the above code you will be able to put ordered/unordered lists in table.